# separating 2d numpy array into nxn chunks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

How would you separate a 2D `numpy` array into a nxn chunks?

For example, the following array of shape *(4,4)*:

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4],
       [5,6,7,8],
       [9,10,11,12],
       [13,14,15,16]]
```

Transformed to this array, of shape *(4,2,2)*, by subsampling with a different *(2x2)* array:

```
new_arr = [[[1,2],
            [5,6]],
           [[3,4],
            [7,8]],
           [[9,10],
            [13,14]],
           [[11,12],
            [15,16]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.vsplit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html) to split the array into multiple subarrays vertically. Similarly you can use [np.hsplit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html) to split the array into multiple subarrays horizontally. To better understand this examine the generalized `resample` function which makes the use of `np.vsplit` and `np.hsplit` methods.

**Use this:**

```
def ressample(arr, N):
    A = []
    for v in np.vsplit(arr, arr.shape[0] // N):
        A.extend([*np.hsplit(v, arr.shape[0] // N)])
    return np.array(A)
```

---

**Example 1:**
The given 2D array is of shape 4x4 and we want to subsample it into the chunks of shape 2x2.

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                [5, 6, 7, 8],
                [9, 10, 11, 12],
                [13, 14, 15, 16]])  
print(ressample(arr, 2)) #--> chunk size 2
```

**Output 1:**

```
[[[ 1  2]
  [ 5  6]]

 [[ 3  4]
  [ 7  8]]

 [[ 9 10]
  [13 14]]

 [[11 12]
  [15 16]]]
```

---

**Example 2:**
Consider the given 2D array contains 8 rows and 8 columns. Now we subsample this array into the chunks of shape 4x4.

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, 64).reshape(8, 8)   
print(ressample(arr, 4)) #--> chunck size 4
```

**Sample Output 2:**

```
[[[8 3 7 5]
  [7 2 6 1]
  [7 9 2 2]
  [3 1 8 8]]

 [[2 0 3 2]
  [2 9 0 8]
  [2 6 3 9]
  [2 4 4 8]]

 [[9 9 1 8]
  [9 1 5 0]
  [8 5 1 2]
  [2 7 5 1]]

 [[7 8 9 6]
  [9 0 9 5]
  [8 9 8 3]
  [7 3 6 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, and adjust it to your array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [[1,2,3,4],
       [5,6,7,8],
       [9,10,11,12],
       [13,14,15,16]]

arr_new = np.array([[arr[i][j:j+2], arr[i+1][j:j+2]] for j in range(len(arr[0])-2) for i in range(len(arr)-2)])
print(arr_new)
print(arr_new.shape)
```

This gives the following output:

```
[[[ 1  2]
  [ 5  6]]

 [[ 5  6]
  [ 9 10]]

 [[ 2  3]
  [ 6  7]]

 [[ 6  7]
  [10 11]]]
(4, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `hsplit()` and `vsplit()` methods to achieve the above.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])

ls1,ls2 = np.hsplit(arr, 2)
ls1 = np.vsplit(ls1,2)
ls2 = np.vsplit(ls2,2)
ls = ls1 + ls2
result = np.array(ls)

print(result)

>>> 
 [[[ 1  2]
  [ 5  6]]

 [[ 9 10]
  [13 14]]

 [[ 3  4]
  [ 7  8]]

 [[11 12]
  [15 16]]]

print(result.tolist())

>>> [[[1, 2], [5, 6]], [[9, 10], [13, 14]], [[3, 4], [7, 8]], [[11, 12], [15, 16]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to split or anything; the same can be achieved by reshaping and reordering the axes.

```
result = np.swapaxes(arr.reshape(2, 2, 2, 2), 1, 2).reshape(-1, 2, 2)
```

Dividing an (N, N) array to (n, n) chunks is also basically a sliding window op with an (n, n) window and a stride of n.

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

result = sliding_window_view(arr, (2, 2))[::2, ::2].reshape(-1, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using just one line with `scipy`:

```py
import scipy

arr = [[1,2,3,4],
       [5,6,7,8],
       [9,10,11,12],
       [13,14,15,16]]

arr1 = scipy.sparse.bsr_matrix(arr, blocksize=(2,2)).data
print(arr1)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 1  2]
  [ 5  6]]

 [[ 3  4]
  [ 7  8]]

 [[ 9 10]
  [13 14]]

 [[11 12]
  [15 16]]]
```

You can then reshape `arr1` as well if needed.